# how to open a new webpage on button click from a submit form in ruby on rails 4.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails. I have a create.html.erb view file in my rails application. There is a text field in it. When i click the submit button, i need to open another webpage and pass the text entered in the text field to that webpage. How can do this? How can i give the url of the new webpage and route to that url on the button click?

I tried to give the url in routes.rb like this:
post "/blog" => redirect("http://example.com/blog")

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the URL in your form:

```
 <% form_for @person :url => your_url, :method => "post" do |f| %>
```

Then get the text from your parameters in your controller:

```
<%= f.input :user, :input_html => { :value => params[:text] } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that didn't work for me. I can't figure out the correct syntax for form_for. When i use form_for, it is showing internal error. Can i use form_tag for this purpose?